# How do I get Novel edirectory detail using C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, ldap, novell

Recently I got an assignment for work in Novell Edirectory. As I am very new to this so i am facing lots of trouble on this way. Can anybody help me to get the idea how to find below information using C++.

1. Is local machine is having Novell Edirectory support.
2. What is the DN(Domain Name) it has
3. How to get user detail from the logged in Novel Edirectory.

Any idea or link will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the reason for the Active-Directory flag ?

Comment: currently I am unaware of main objective but my primary assignment is to find the above detail and I am unable, please help me to get start at least

Answer (score 0):

What protocol/approach are you intending to use?  An LDAP connection?  Or NCP using Client32?  That is your first question to answer.

If LDAP there is no real difference, most LDAP tools will work just fine.

If NCP then you are writing to Client32 and its NCP libraries, which you can find info about at developer.novell.com